# Build app with App Inventor 2 that includes saved data

Tags: android, app-inventor

Using App Inventor 2 how to include a saved data (text file or csv) that already holds data to be used the an app to view that data?

I mean building application with already stored data to be viewed by anyone install the app. How to include the file with apk package.

Answer (score 0):

Just upload the text file into the assets of the app and read it using the `file` component.... Yes, it's that simple...

[How to read a file stored as asset in App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2readfile)

[image]